# Range does not allow properties to be added or changed - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to edit/delete a range a user creates?

```
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Quotation");
   var range = ss.getRangeByName("quoteLines");
   var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(range.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 10);

  sheet.insertRowAfter(range.getLastRow());
  rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(range.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
  ss. newRange = sheet.getRange(19, 1, range.getLastRow() - 19, 10);
  ss.removeNamedRange('quoteLines'); <!-- added since I couldn't directly edit range
  ss.setNamedRange('quoteLines', newRange);
```

The code above tries to add a line to with formatting to an existing range and then replace that range (since I can't figure out how to just extend the range by 1 row). I've defined the range by hand inside the worksheet but I get the error

`Object does not allow properties to be added or changed`

on the range `quoteLines`.

Comment: Have you checked if `newRange` is actually a valid range? What does 19 mean?

Comment: Have you tried using the [appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#appendRow%28Object%29) in order to do that?

Comment: `newRange` is a valid range, the 19 is the row it starts on, that's hardcoded.

@pointNclick appendRow only appends a row to the end of the spreadsheet, not to the end of a range

Answer (score 0):

To extend the range by 1 Row, you should use the `offset` function.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sname = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name);
  var sRange = sname.getDataRange();
  Logger.log(sRange.getLastRow());
  var newRange = sRange.offset(1, 0);
  Logger.log(newRange.getLastRow());
```

This will result in the range being increased by 1 Row while the number of columns remain the same. For more info, please take a look at this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset%28Integer,Integer%29). Below is a screenshot of my log output.

[image]

Hope this helps!